# CentOS 7 on XenServer 6.5

Tags: centos, xen, xenserver, centos7

I am having problem trying to get CentOS 7 Graphical installer to work on XenServer 6.5 (Service pack 1).

I have used CentOS 7 template.

Graphical installer does not work, getting blank screen with cursor only.

I have tried increasing RAM to 2GB and still no luck.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: As an aside to anyone else searching around: I was using TightVNC on a Windows client (usually plays nice with Xen) and experienced this issue.  Using RealVNC worked fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start the installer with inst.vnc option. Select option "Install CentOS 7" and then press [tab]. Remove 'quiet' and add 'inst.vnc' to kernel command line. Press [enter].

[image: Selecting VNC installation mode.]

After that, wait till the kernel spins up, and you'll end up with the following message:

[image]

All you need to do now is use vnc client to connect to IP shown in the message. Port is the standard one, 5901.

Answer (score 0):

When you getting blank screen with blinking cursor, just restart XenCenter and navigate to the tab "Console" of the new VM and you will see correctly presented GUI.